# save Object to file

Tags: java, file, object

I need to save a object with all it's properties to a file.

I am not allowed to change the Class of the Object.
The Object is unserializable.
So how am I able to save the Object to a file for later usage?

Comment: Its hard for me to explain.
I just have an object and need to save it to the disk.

Comment: Upvoted pointless unexplained downvote. The quality of these comments is depressing. I never understand why people comment on things they don't understand, or when they just don't know what they're talking about.

Comment: @StefanoSanfillipo The only link necessary is that I saw fit to mention them both in one comment instead of two. Perhaps you could stop nitpicking and learn something about the topic of this thread. Your presence here is otherwise inexplicable.

Comment: @EJP Ok, I guess I was just to quick to draw a conclusion, not considering all (independent from Serializable) possibilities. Now that I see the answers. I am removing the first comment.

Answer (score 2):

If the object conforms to the Java Beans Specification (other than the Serializable requirement) you can use the java.beans.XMLEncoder.

Comment: The OP specifically said that his/her object is unserializable. JavaBeans specification requires at §5.5 that "all beans must support either Serialization or Externalization", so his/her object does not conform the Java Beans Specification.

Comment: @StefanoSanfillipo Nevertheless there is no such requirement as Serializable with this encoder, as you could also have discovered by looking it up, or trying it for yourself, instead of making wild claims about things you know nothing about.

Comment: I was just trying to help you make this answer more accurate by leaving a comment. I'm sorry if you think this is nitpicking. I recognize I did not investigate this method, nevertheless I saw an incongruence and I felt like notifying you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are avoiding the default java serialization, there are two options.

You can either write a custom writer and reader where you msnually write your values to a file. You can also have a reader that reads a file and returns an object. This is a lot of work and not worth it.

Another option is to use a JSON or XML serialization library (which does not use java serialization).

eg: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 0):

Saving an object in a file means saving its state, fields. You can try `java.io.DataOutputStream` which has all necessary methods to save any primitive types and Strings. You can later recreate the object with reading its fields from file with `java.io.DataInputStream`. It depends on the object class, but if even the object is not a bean, that is it does not allow to read / set its fields, you still can try and use reflection to access its fields.

Answer (score 0):

It does not work with all cases but you can use `ObjectOutputStream`.

Assuming your class `Foo` is not serializable. Create another `FooState` to contain a Foo instance state

```
public class Foo {
    private String string;
    private Date date;
    /* ... */
}

public class FooState {
    private String string;
    private Date date;

    public FooState(Foo foo) {
        this.string = foo.getString();
        this.date = foo.getDate();
        /* ... */
    }

    private Object readResolve() throws ObjectStreamException {
        return new Foo(string, date, ...);
    }
}
```

Then subclass `ObjectOutputStream`. With this class it is possible to transparently substitute a non-serializable objet by a serializable one for both serialization and deserialization.

```
public class FooObjOutputStream extends ObjectOutputStream {
    public FooObjOutputStream(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        super(out);
        enableReplaceObject(true);
    }

    protected FooObjOutputStream() throws IOException, SecurityException {
        super();
        enableReplaceObject(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected Object replaceObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
        if (obj instanceof Foo) {
            return new FooState((Foo) obj);
        } else {
            return super.replaceObject(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

And then for serialization/deserialization

```
private static byte[] serialize(Object o) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    FooObjOutputStream oos = new FooObjOutputStream(baos); // Magically handling Foo objects
    oos.writeObject(o);
    oos.flush();
    oos.close();
    return baos.toByteArray();
}

public static Object deserialize(byte[] bytes) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
    Object o = ois.readObject();
    bais.close();
    return o;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to use a third party library, you can try using a serialization library like [Kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo).